# How does scrollable tabs + swipe work?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have for the last couple of hours been trying to figure out how it works. It is one of the navigation options that appears after you create a blank activity. I'm just not sure how the fragments are added to the tabs unless they are just inflating the layout xml's. I just wanted to know because I wanted to have textviews on one, buttons on another, and a litview on a third.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The swipe functionality is accomplished using a `ViewPager`. `ViewPager` is a `ViewGroup` that allows pages (i.e. `Fragments`) to be scrolled horizontally. `Fragments` are added to the `ViewPager` via a `PagerAdapter`. Typically you would use either `FragementPagerAdapter` or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`; these two classes are implementations of `PagerAdapter`. If you look at these `PagerAdapter` implementations you will see that you need to implement `getItem(int)` and `getCount()`. It is in `getItem(int)` where you return an instance of a `Fragment`; typically you can use a data structure like `List<Fragment>` and return the specific `Fragment` you want based on the `int` that is passed. `getCount()` is used to determine the total pages to display; going back to the `List` example you can use `List.size()` to determine how many "pages" you need.

Comment: Do you have a link to a piece of code? I'm new to android app development.

Comment: The best way to learn this is by creating a new project with the "Tabs + Swipe" template.

Comment: That's what I did. I'm guessing I need a separate class for each fragment? I might not answer back until later.

Comment: Yes. If the layout is significantly different you will need different `Fragments`

Comment: OK so it would be like if current tab is home the inflate home.class?

Comment: You will inflate the layout inside the respective's `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()`.

Comment: I meant to say how do I know what tab I'm on?

Comment: The template implements [`TabListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.TabL‌​istener.html) which has a methods that tells you the different states of the Tab. You can get the Tab's position with its `getPosition()`.

Comment: Ok so I've been reading up on fragments and viewpager a little and it seems that there is only one activity and all that does is inflate the .xml layouts. Is that correct?

Comment: are you referring to `Fragments` or `ViewPager`?

Comment: I want to say fragments. You would inflate the .xml's in 'public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
   Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
   switch (position) {
   case 0:
    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
   case 1:
    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
   case 2:
    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
   }
   return null;
  }'                                                                 sorry if I am being a pain but I just don't understand how it works.

Comment: `Fragments` were created to give `Activities` more flexibility. One `Activity` can manage many `Fragments`. A `Fragment's` layout is inflated in the `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()`; `getPageTitle()` is used by the `ViewPager` to get the page's title.

Comment: Ok its starting to make more sense. So lets say i have an app with 2 tabs, Home and contacts. Would I want to have 2 separate classes or just load a different .xml layout each time?

Comment: I think it will be easier to have two separate `Fragment`s with one xml for each.

Comment: I honestly feel really bad for keeping this going on but when you create the template where `@Override
  public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
   Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
   
   switch (position) {
   case 0:
    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
   case 1:
    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
   case 2:
    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
   }
   return null;
  }` I'm guessing that in-between each of the cases is where I would put whatever code changes the fragments?